# C# Windows application throwing Side by Side error on start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, manifest

[image]

When trying to start applications, there is a side by side error. From given error message in event viewer, it looks like configuration error. I have corrected dll version in manifest file to match with referenced dll. Even after correcting that, I still get same error.

Comment: Based on my research, the error shows that the machine is missing the correct C++ runtime components for your type of system. (x86 or x64). Therefore, I want to know what the current visual studio version is, which may help us to solve your problem.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 15 at the moment

Comment: If so, I suggest that  you can download [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) to try to solve the problem.